# How to generate Intervals from a given list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

If I have a list

```
list={3,7,4,5,1}
```

how to get the List of Intervals /Ranges

```
result = {{1,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,7}}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe

```
Partition[Sort@list, 2, 1]
```

giving

> {{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 7}}

**Update**

In addition,

```
BlockMap[#&, Sort[list], 2,1]

(* {{1,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,7}} *)
```

Comment: Beat me to it - 7 secs! Deleting mine, and +1.

Answer (score 7):

Tom's answer is canonical, but you could also use:

```
With[{s = Sort[list]}, Transpose[{Most[s], Rest[s]}]]
```

which seems to be marginally faster for large lists.  (In which case most of the time is spent sorting.)

Comment: Alternatively: `Composition[Transpose, Through, {Most, Rest}, Sort][list]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Subsets`, `Sort` and the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
list = {3, 7, 4, 5, 1};

Values@GroupBy[Subsets[Sort@#, {2}], First, First] &@list

(*{{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 7}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {3, 7, 4, 5, 1};

Query[{Most, Rest} /* Transpose] @ Sort[list]
```

{{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 7}}