# How to generate the list of consecutive pairs from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the morally right solution to mapping a list {a,b,c,...} to the list of pairs {{a,b},{b,c},{c,..},..}?

The solution I came up with feels a little clumsy: Shift a copied list by one and form an Inner product.

Comment: [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) : _Partition[list,n,d]
generates sublists with offset d._, e.g., `Partition[{a,b,c,d,e},2,1]`

Comment: @kguler: Mathematicas in-build functions for everything always make me look like an idiot.

Comment: i know the feeling:)

Comment: this question has an answer in [How to generate Intervals from a given list?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/427/how-to-generate-intervals-from-a-given-list)