# How can I obtain a list of all consecutive pairs of elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, given

```
{a,b,c,d}
```

I want

```
{{a,b},{b,c},{c,d}}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]`

Comment: @chyanog Yes, that is the right way.

Comment: Also asked here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80566/how-to-generate-the-list-of-consecutive-pairs-from-a-list

Comment: And just for fun only `lst = {a, b, c, d};
MapIndexed[(idx = First[#2]; If[idx < Length@lst, lst[[idx ;; idx + 1]], Nothing]) &, lst]` gives `{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it using `Transpose` and `Take`

```
{a,b,c,d}
Transpose[{%[[;; -2]], %[[2 ;;]]}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}
> ```